# C# Connecting a console app to a Library Class project containing Entity Framework database access

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I currently have a solution with three projects:

- one contains my ASP.NET MVC app
- another is a class library that contains Entity Framework data models and data context
- and a console application that will be a service that needs access to the database as well

I'm currently having trouble figuring out how to allow my console app to connect to the class library project to get data. What all do I need to do?

I have a static class in my class library project that acts as a db helper. When I make a call to this in my console project I get ADO.NET errors. I've tried to add connection strings to the `app.config` and then I start to get errors about how I can't attach the instance because there is already a database with the same name.

What steps do I need to take to successfully access data in my console project from my class library project that contains all the Entity Framework data models?

Comment: you'll simply need to add a reference to you DAL project, create a context and do your operations. For this you'll have to keep a few things in mind: -Although EF can go with any connection string/connection, if a name is specified, it will look for it in the *calling* project's app.config. -All participating projects (those that actually "use" the EF functionality) need EF installed, where version/provider differences might cause errors.

Comment: Add reference to your Services Class Library and call methods which will deal with Db Connections.